# Calculate Points Between Two Points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two points $(A, B)$, both with longitude and latitude. For each point I have a speed in $km/h$, I assume a car drives from point $A$ to point $B$.

I already have a function to calculate the distance between the two points.

What I want to calculate in the end is the points between this two points in a distance of $100$ milliseconds (every $100ms$ I want to calculate a point)

The way between the points does not have any curves in it, it is a straight line.

Thanks for your help

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $A=[x_A ~ y_A]$ and $B = [x_B ~ y_B]$, a point between $A$ and $B$ can be described as

$$C = \alpha(B-A) + A$$

for $\alpha \in [0, 1]$

When $\alpha = 1$, the you arrive to $B$. If you travel with a constant velocity $v$ and the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $d$, then

$$\alpha = \frac{vt}{d}$$

The point after $100$ ms $= 0.1$s is

$$C(0.1s) = \frac{0.1v}{d}(B-A)+A$$

The point after $0.2s$ is

$$C(0.2s) = \frac{0.2v}{d}(B-A)+A$$

and so on...

Notice that $v$ must be expressed in [km]/[s] if $d$ is [km] or [m]/[s] if $d$ is [m].

Comment: Thx, but I don't think that this is correct, cause it means that I would need always 1 second to reach point B. Waht one need is: a) The acceleration b) the distance (what I have) and then you need to calculate the time you need to reach point B. Then you can calculate how many points you have if the distance is 100ms for each point (e.g. 10 seconds = 100 points). each points gets then it's own speed you need to calculate... any ides on how to do this?

Comment: Any other ideas? First of all I have to findout the time I need to travel from A to B. Then I can findout how many points O have in between and then I can use the formula above.