# Dumbing down 2d cooridinates between two known points

Tags: linear-algebra

I've searched using various terms and [Calculate Points Between Two Points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870634/calculate-points-between-two-points), [Incremental Cartensian Coordinates Betwwen Two Known Coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871082/incremental-cartensian-coordinates-betwwen-two-known-coordinates) and  [Calculating the x, y coordinate a set distance between two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244598/calculating-the-x-y-coordinate-a-set-distance-between-two-points) which I thought had the answer but tests in Excel do not give the expected results.

I have $P_{1,x}, P_{1,y}, P_{2,x} , P_{2,y}$. The object at $P_1$ moves with at a constant speed towards $P_2$. I need to plot each point along a straight line toward $P_2$ but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object moves with speed $S$, then its position at time $t$ after it starts at $P_1$ will be $P_1+St V$, where $V$ is the direction vector from $P_1$ to $P_2$ normalized to have length $1$:
$$
V = \frac{P_2-P_1}{\|P_2-P_1\|} = \bigg( \frac{P_{2,x}-P_{1,x}}{\sqrt{(P_{2,x}-P_{1,x})^2+(P_{2,y}-P_{1,y})^2}},\, \frac{P_{2,y}-P_{1,y}}{\sqrt{(P_{2,x}-P_{1,x})^2+(P_{2,y}-P_{1,y})^2}} \bigg).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @greg-martin. I take it that I add StV to the x and y of P1?

Comment: Yes, adding vectors is done in the usual way: add $St$ times the first coordinate of $V$ to $P_{1,x}$, and similarly for second coordinates.

Comment: I had to look up https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120904161845AAVqe0b for help with your notation which is not supprising as I also had to look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics) to remind me which is the divisor.
I think I got it…

Comment: I don't go it. Found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244598/calculating-the-x-y-coordinate-a-set-distance-between-two-points?lq=1 that helped.